# filter, copy and past the row without header in vba

Tags: vba

I want to copy the filtered data and paste it in difference excel file. I am able to filter , copy and paste the rows. The only problem I am facing is that it is also copying and pasting the header every time. Please advise as to how to avoid header to be pasted.

```
If Not ws1.AutoFilterMode Then
    ws1.Range("D1").AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="=Gaus", Criteria2:="=Shaikh", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    RowCount = ws1.Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(2, Range("A2:A1048576"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will copy the visible cells without a header row.

```
Dim rSource As Range
Set rSource = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1)

rSource.Resize(rSource.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```